# Can not make rendering of html <select><option value="id".... with select-input formlet

Tags: racket

I trying to use select-input formlet to render an

```
<SELECT ...><OPTION value="1">item1</OPTION><OPTION value="2">item2</OPTION></SELECT>
```

according to a documentation select-input expects 1 obligatory argument which is of type sequence? when i try to give an

```
(in-hash (make-hash (list (cons 1 "Item1") (cons 2 "Item2"))))
```

as such argument it throws exception:

```
context expected 1 value, received 2 values: 1 "Item1"
```

it is ok when i use list of "Item1" "Item2"
How can i implement rendering of selection with values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select-input will pick the values for you and guarantee that the right thing comes out. So

```
((select-input (list "Item1" "Item2")) . => . ans)
```

will return `"Item1"` or `"Item2"` into `ans`.
It will pick the HTML "value" behind the scenes.

If you actually want 1 and 2 to return you could do:

```
((select-input (list 1 2)
               #:display (lambda (n) (format "Item~a" n)))
 . => . ans)
```

Now ans will have 1 or 2 but it will be displayed as Item1 or Item2

Jay